# Edit wordpress Shopp plugin to enable promo-code input

Tags: wordpress, shopp

I want to enable a promo-code input box for the Shopp plugin on wordpress.

The documentation says that to get the promo box to show up I need to add the following PHP to the template file:

```
<?php shopp('cart','promo-code'); ?>
```

I am new to the wordpress CMS and do not know which template file this this should be added to / where to look. If anyone has done this I would really appreciate the details of where to add this PHP to enable the feature. All the tutorials focus on creating the promotions in the cpanel but do not cover turning on the promo input box with PHP.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a Theme API tag that is usually added to the shopping cart template file. When custom templates are setup in your theme the file is located somewheres around `wp-content/themes/yourtheme/shopp/cart.php`. Note that `yourtheme` represents the directory name of your active WordPress theme files.

Shopp has starter templates built in that you can copy to your theme files. Editing the template files in the Shopp plugin is not recommended because you will lose your changes with each upgrade.

You can copy the files from Shopp to your theme yourself, or you can use the built-in system for copying them. More information about these templates and how to install them into your theme for customization can be found in the Shopp User Guide documentation in the [Theme Templates](https://shopplugin.net/docs/the-catalog/theme-templates/) article.